# Placing ChartObjects in Excel or making Objects into One Series

Tags: excel, vba, charts, histogram

My code currently creates 2 histograms with ChartObjects. Using ChartObject relies on you to specify where you will be physically placing the charts in spreadsheets (which I don't want since there are 2 charts and these 2 charts can be repeated numerous times in my application).

I am trying to switch them from ChartObject to Objects so that they dont overlap, however when doing so the data and axes ranges for the series (which are both dynamic in size and location) interpret each point in the range as its own series. In most examples for Objects I have seen the ranges were static and directly beside each other (ex. A1:B5), which is not the case for the data I am using.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! See snapshot where the left is the desired chart appearance.

[image: charts]

See code below

```
Dim GammaSetChart As ChartObject
Dim GammaSetData As Range, GammaSetAxes As Range
Set GammaSetChart = ws3.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=300, Top:=7, Height:=200)
Set GammaSetData = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(2 + emptyRow, num_sims + num_sims2 + 2), ws3.Cells(2 + emptyRow + num_source_bins, num_sims + num_sims2 + 2))
GammaSetChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=GammaSetData
Set GammaSetAxes = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(2 + emptyRow, 1 + num_sims), ws3.Cells(num_source_bins + 1 + emptyRow, 1 + num_sims))
GammaSetChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = GammaSetAxes

Dim SimChart As Object
Dim SimData As Range, SimAxes As Range
'Set SimChart = ws3.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=300, Top:=7, Height:=200)
Set SimChart = ws3.Shapes.AddChart2
Set SimData = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(4 + emptyRow + num_source_bins, num_sims + 3), ws3.Cells(4 + emptyRow + num_source_bins + num_sim_set_bins, num_sims + 3))
'Set SimData = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(2 + emptyRow, num_sims + num_sims2 + 2), ws3.Cells(2 + emptyRow + num_source_bins, num_sims + num_sims2 + 2))
SimChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=SimData
Set SimAxes = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(4 + emptyRow + num_source_bins, 1 + num_sims), ws3.Cells(3 + emptyRow + num_source_bins + y, 1 + num_sims))
'Set GammaSetAxes = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(2 + emptyRow, 1 + num_sims), ws3.Cells(num_source_bins + 1 + emptyRow, 1 + num_sims))
SimChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = SimAxes
```

Comment: "I am trying to switch them from ChartObject to Objects so that they dont overlap" - it's not clear why you think this would make any difference?  Even if you declare it as `Object` it's still a `ChartObject`   If you're having a problem with how to place them, that can likely be done by positioning them relative to a known range eg `Set c = Range("D4"): ChartObjects.Add(Left:=c.Left, Width:=300, Top:=c.Top, Height:=200)`

Comment: Also helps to explicitly set `Chart.ChartType` to the type of chart you want to create, before adding any data series.